# eliminar item de una lista React js todolist

Tags: reactjs

**Aqui esta la parte de las funciones de mi codigo para que me funcione el todolist, igual se tengo mas error de lo que s ve y me corriguen se lo agradeceria, todavia me cuesta el funcionamiento de react**

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from "react";



export const TodoList = () => {
    const [lista, setlista] = useState([]);
const agregarList = e => {
    if (event.key == "Enter" && e.target.value != "") {
        setlista([...lista, e.target.value]);
    }
};

const DeleteItems = index => {
    const { index } = lista.filter(i != index;)
};
```

**Aqui le agrego el html con los demas para que observen el comportamiento, intente hacer varios ejercicios que vi pero la verdad,no me sirve ninguno, necesito ayuda con esto**

```
return (
    <Fragment>
        <h2 className="d-flex justify-content-center text-center">
            TO-DO LIST
        </h2>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Escribe tu tarea"
                onKeyPress={agregarList}
            />
        </div>

        <br />
        <div className="text-center">
            <ul>
                {lista.map((item, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>
                        {item}
                        <button className="btn" onClick={DeleteItems}>
                            <i className="fas fa-trash-alt" />
                        </button>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </Fragment>
);
```

};

Comment: const lista = lista.filter(i != index;)

Comment: abajo de const DeleteItems = index =>

Comment: lo utilice mas no me sirve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eliminar un elemento dentro de un arreglo existen varias formas, en este caso contamos con un arreglo de strings únicamente, por lo cual la mejor opción es eliminar el elemento a partir de index del arreglo, esto debido a que si utilizamos el nombre del "ToDo" podríamos eliminar mas de un elemento sin querer.

A tu callback del evento para eliminar elementos lo modificaría de la siguiente manera:

```
  const DeleteItems = (indexItem) => {
    setlista((prevState) =>
      prevState.filter((todo, index) => index !== indexItem)
    );
  };
```

A su vez se tiene que modificar tu código dentro del componente para pasar el index del elemento desde el evento, quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <h2 className="d-flex justify-content-center text-center">TO-DO LIST</h2>
  <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Escribe tu tarea"
      onKeyPress={agregarList}
    />
  </div>

  <br />
  <div className="text-center">
    <ul>
      {lista.map((item, index) => (
        <li key={index}>
          {item}
          <button className="btn" onClick={() => DeleteItems(index)}>
            <i className="fas fa-trash-alt" />
          </button>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias a sido de mucha ayuda